# How do you delete an entire column of data in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to only use the DELETE statement to delete an entire column of data. Is this possibly without having to type out each individual where condition? I still want to have my column, but just delete/clear the data using the the DELETE statement.

Comment: I guess you need update instead of delete

Comment: To answer the questions you asked. No, it's not possible to "clear" the data in a column with a `DELETE` statement, no matter how many individual WHERE conditions you type out. The DELETE statement will not perform the actions you specify. You could use an `UPDATE` statement to change the values stored in the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET column = NULL;
```

or

```
UPDATE table SET column = ''; -- if column is not nullable
```

If there are a lot of rows, you might as well go for

```
ALTER TABLE `table` DROP COLUMN `column`
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD COLUMN (`column` COLUMN DEFINITION)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 1):

just use an `UPDATE` statement.

### **QUERY**

```
UPDATE tableName
SET columnName = NULL;
```

It will make all the data in that particular column to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Droping the column can be done with:

```
ALTER TABLE 'table' DROP 'column';
```

Setting all values to null can be done with:

```
UPDATE table SET column = NULL;
```

Comment: OP don't want to drop the column

Comment: I know. But i also answer how to do it without droping the column.

Comment: So there's no way to do it with the DELETE statement?

Comment: I guess no... Why do you want to do it with the DELETE statement so sincerely?

Comment: It was just a curiosity to find alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If your column IS NULLable then execute

```
UPDATE youtable_name
SET yourcolumn_name = NULL;
```

Otherwise you may have to set it to other value depending on your column type

If the column type string (ie. text, char, varchar) and not NULLable

```
 UPDATE youtable_name
 SET yourcolumn_name = '';
```

Or if the column in numeric type (ie. Int, double, decimal.....) and not NULLable then execute

```
UPDATE youtable_name
SET yourcolumn_name = 0;
```